# Pasar una variable con valor unico a otra clase

Tags: php, laravel

tengo dos clases

```
class class1 extends Controller
{

    public function fun 1($xxxxxx){

             $sCliente = new Client;
                $sCliente->xxxx = $oData->xxx->id;
                $sCliente->name = xxx->fullName;
                $sCliente->xxxx = xxxx->email;
                $sCliente->id_usuario = $aClient['xxxxx'];
                $sCliente->save();

          $oIdCliente = $sCliente->id; // esto es para obtener el id 
    }
}
```

y esta es mi otra clase

```
class class2 extends Controller
{
    public function fun2($xxx){

            $oIdClient = $this->ctrCliente()->createUser();

    }
}
```

lo que estoy intentando es pasar por medio de `$oIdCliente = $sCliente->id;` pasar `id` valor del `create` a la otra clase pero no logro que se obtenga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está medio confuso tu código y tu explicación porque en tu primer clase, instancías un objeto de la clase Client y no sabemos de donde sale al igual que en la segunda clase, estás llamando a un método de la clase que no sabemos si existe, qué es lo que hace, etc.

Bueno, para acceder a acciones o propiedades de controlador a controlador, no deberías, no estarías siguiendo el patrón de Laravel, si necesitas pasar valores o usar métodos de un controlador a otro controlador tendrías que considerar hacer un re-factor de tu código y crear una clase de servicio.

Tu estructura quedaría algo parecido a esto:

```
class UsersService
{
  public function getId()
  {
    // tu implementación aquí.
  }
}

//No olvides importar la clase servicio antes
class Clase1 extends Controller
{
  protected $userService;
  public function __construct(UsersService $userService)
  {
     $this->userService = $userService;
  }

  public function create() 
  {
    // llamar al método
    $this->userService->getId();
    // lo demás acá
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas crear diferentes archivos con clases tu mejor opción es utilizar los traits.

Ejemplo 
En mi archivo casePrincipal.php tengo

```
namespace \App;
class clasePrinsipal extends Controller {
     use \App\trait;
     function funcion1(){
         $this->function2($valor);
     }
}
```

Ahora construyendo su trait quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```
 namespace \App;
    trait masclases {

         function funcion2($valor){
             Aqui haces loq ue tengas que hacer con el valor que mandas 
             desde la primera funcion

         }
    }
```

No olvides que dependiendo de la estructura de carpetas se construye el namespace